# Грамматически правильное продолжение предложения

Tags: орфография

**Наклеивая обои,**
1)требуется прежде всего аккуратность.
2) нужно следить , чтобы не образовались морщины
3) лицевая сторона должна быть сухой
4) многое зависит от качества клея

Answer (score 5):

Верный ответ второй. Деепричастие и глагол-сказуемое должны обозначать действие одного субъекта. Кто наклеивает, тот и должен следить.

Answer (score 2):

2) нужно следить , чтобы не образовались морщины